# Parsing equations from stdin

Tags: c, parsing, matrix, mathematics, math-expression-eval

The program should read equations from `stdin`, parse them and generate a matrix of the coefficient which represents the system.

Example:

```
$ ./eqs
x + y = 4
-y + 4x = 2

  1   1   4 
  4  -1   2
```

As you can see, the user can input as many equations they want and the program stops reading when an empty line is sent.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define _M(i, j) (M->elements[(i) * M->cols + (j)])
#define ROWS 10
#define CHUNK 32

typedef struct {
    size_t rows;
    size_t cols;
    double *elements;
} Matrix;

void print_matrix(Matrix *);
Matrix *parse_input();
Matrix *create_matrix(size_t, size_t);
void free_matrix(Matrix *);
int readline(char **, size_t *, FILE *);
void memory_error(void);


int main(void) {
    Matrix *M = parse_input();
    print_matrix(M);
    free_matrix(M);
    return 0;
}


void print_matrix(Matrix *M) {
    size_t i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < M->rows; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < M->cols; j++) {
            printf("%3g ", _M(i, j));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}


Matrix *parse_input() {
    char *row;
    size_t reading_size = CHUNK;
    if (!(row = malloc(reading_size))) memory_error();
    double coeff;
    size_t i, j, k, numrows = ROWS;
    double **unknowns;
    if (!(unknowns = malloc(numrows * sizeof(*unknowns)))) {
        free(row);
        memory_error();
    }
    for (i = 0 ; i < numrows; i++) {
        if (!(unknowns[i] = calloc(27, sizeof(**unknowns)))) {
            free(unknowns);
            memory_error();
        }
    }
    i = 0;
    do {
        if (i == numrows) {
            numrows *= 2;
            for (j = i + 1; j < numrows; j++) {
                if (!(unknowns[j] = calloc(27, sizeof(**unknowns)))) {
                    free(unknowns);
                    memory_error();
                }
            }
        }
        readline(&row, &reading_size, stdin);
        char *p = row;
        unsigned char past_equal = 0;
        coeff = 1;
        while (*p) {
            if (*p == '-') {
                coeff *= -1;
                p++;
            } else if (*p == '=') {
                past_equal = 1;
                p++;
            } else if (isdigit(*p)) {
                double val = strtod(p, &p);
                if (!past_equal) coeff *= val;
                else {
                    unknowns[i][26] = val;
                    break;
                }
            } else if (isalpha(*p)) {
                unknowns[i][tolower(*p++) - 'a'] = coeff;
                coeff = 1;
            } else p++;
        }
        i++;
    } while (row[0] != '\0');
    free(row);
    i--;
    unsigned short int nonzero_unknowns[27] = {0};
    nonzero_unknowns[26] = 1;
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        for (k = 0; k < 26; k++) {
            if (unknowns[j][k]) nonzero_unknowns[k] = 1;
        }
    }
    size_t ncols = 0;
    unsigned short int positions[26];
    for (j = 0; j < 26; j++) {
        if (nonzero_unknowns[j]) {
            positions[ncols++] = j;
        }
    }
    ncols++;
    if (i + 1 < ncols) {
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            free(unknowns[j]);
        }
        free(unknowns);
        puts("The system is underdetermined.");
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    Matrix *M = create_matrix(i, ncols);
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        for (k = 0; k + 1 < ncols; k++) {
            _M(j, k) = unknowns[j][positions[k]];
        }
        _M(j, k) = unknowns[j][26];
    }
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        free(unknowns[j]);
    }
    free(unknowns);
    return M;
}


Matrix *create_matrix(size_t rows, size_t cols) {
    Matrix *M;
    if (!(M = malloc(sizeof *M))) memory_error();
    M->rows = rows;
    M->cols = cols;
    if (!(M->elements = calloc(rows * cols, sizeof(double)))) {
        free(M);
        memory_error();
    }
    return M;
}


void free_matrix(Matrix *M) {
    free(M->elements);
    free(M);
}


int readline(char **input, size_t *size, FILE *file) {
    char *offset;
    char *p;
    size_t old_size;

    // Already at the end of file
    if (!fgets(*input, *size, file)) {
        return EOF;
    }

    // Check if input already contains a newline
    if ((p = strchr(*input, '\n'))) {
        *p = 0;
        return 0;
    }

    do {
        old_size = *size;
        *size *= 2;
        if (!(*input = realloc(*input, *size))) {
            free(*input);
            memory_error();
        }
        offset = &((*input)[old_size - 1]);
    } while (fgets(offset, old_size + 1, file) &&
             offset[strlen(offset) - 1] != '\n');
    return 0;
}


void memory_error(void) {
    puts("Could not allocate memory.");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

The parsing function is far too large, and it's quite complicated. Here's how the parsing is done:

- a line is read;
- the coefficients are put into the `unknowns` double array, which is `27` doubles wide to hold the `26` coefficients for the lowercase letters and the free term on the RHS of the equation;
- since an equation may not contain all the coefficients (some of them can be zero), the `nonzero_unknowns` holds the count;
- the matrix is initialized and returned.

I think the `parse_input()` function can definitely be broken up into multiple pieces, but I'm having a hard time simplifying it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are some things that may help you improve your code.

### Consider using parser generator tools

If I were writing code like this, I would use `flex` and `bison` (or equivalently `lex` and `yacc`).  There are many resources available for these tools.  Here is [one such resource](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/).

### Eliminate "magic numbers"

Instead of hard-coding the constants 26 and 27 in the code, it would be better to use a `#define` or `const` and name them.

### Fix memory leaks

In the case that there is, say, a single line as input, the program leaks memory.  This is because the `unknowns[i]` or `unknowns[j]` allocates more than enough space, but the loop at the bottom of `parse_input` only frees `i` rows.  Better would be to use a separate variable to track the actual number of allocated unknowns and then use that to drive the loop that frees them.

### Don't bother allocating more memory than needed

There is no benefit to allocating more `unknowns` than needed.  You could simply add them one at a time as needed, since you're allocating them one at a time in a loop anyway.  Just make sure to keep track of the number of allocations so that you can correctly `free` the memory later.

### Consider using streamlining error handling

Much of the code does error checking for `malloc` and then handles the result by freeing memory and then calling `memory_error()` which calls `exit()`.  This is all good practice -- you are well ahead of the pack by actually carefully checking to make sure that the memory allocation suceeeded.  That's great, and I would encourage you to continue this excellent habit.  However, it clutters up the code quite a bit.  An alternative approach would be to create a wrapper function for `malloc` and `calloc` that would enter the address into a flexible data structure.  Then you could have a corresponding `free_all` that would free all allocated memory that could be called either in `main` or in `memory_error`.  This could be done automatically if you register the function with `atexit()`.

### Break apart the `parse_input` function

Your description of the `parse_input` function points the way to how you might break apart the overly-long `parse_input` function.  You could have one function that would create and return the `unknowns` structure.  Then another to parse those into the matrix.

### Minimize redundant loops

The `nonzero_unknowns` array could actually instead be the first row of the `unknowns` array.  That way, you would reduce the number of variables (there are a lot!) and would be able to tally the unknown count as the parsing is done, making things much more efficient.

### Consider handling malformed input lines

If the user types the line `x - 4 = y` the program incorrectly parses this as `1 -4 0`.  Another problem occurs if the user types in `x - x = 0`.  It would be better, I think, to issue a warning to the user or, if you can, perform the algebra to correctly interpret the equation.

### Eliminate `return 0` at the end of `main`

For a long time now, the C language says that finishing `main` will implicitly generate the equivalent to `return 0`.  For that reason, you should eliminate that line from your code.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! I'll implement your suggestions and see if I encounter any problems.